# HTTP Request Failed without a specific reason

Tags: php, http

We are getting sporadic errors `HTTP Request Failed` in the Apache Error log but without a further reason.
The requested URL is on the local server.

I made some tests with a wrong URL and host but this leads to other errors for example

`failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`.

In the apache error.log:

```
[DATE] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /var/www/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762
[DATE] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/" in /var/www/live/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762
```

I checked our Apache error log for the SOAP URL that is being called and the return code is "200".

So what can be the reason for this error?

Comment: It appears you're using Zend Framework. Are you using the MVC it supplies? I ask because your url has `http://example.com/index.php/api/...`. I would expect this to look like `http://example.com/api/...` with index.php handling the request because of a rewrite rule

Comment: It's a Magento shop that uses Zend. The URL is usually working. Only sometimes it fails with that error.